# NodeJS Unexpected token "."

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js, unexpected-token

I have syntax error(**unexpected token "."**) in line `config.db.database;`.
This is my code in file

```
const config = require('../config/config')
const db = {}

const sequelize = new Sequelize({ // SQL constructor
  config.db.database;
  config.db.user;
  config.db.password;
  config.db.option;
});
```

And this is my required config.js code:

```
module.export = {
  port: process.env.PORT || 3011,
  db: {
    database: process.env.DB_NAME || 'tabtracker',
    user: process.env.DB_USER || 'tabtracker',
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD || 'tabtracker',
    options: {
      dialect: process.env.DIALECT || 'sqlite',
      host: process.env.HOST || 'localhost',
      storage: './tabtracker.sqllite'
    }
  }
}
```

Pls help, really dont know how to fix it, I think doing everything right, cuz Im copying a tutorial code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two fundamental errors in that code:

1. You're using a `;` to separate properties in an object initializer; it should be `,`, not `;`
2. You're specifying properties using the new(ish) [*shorthand syntax*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), but you can only do that with a simple identifier, not a property access expression such as `config.db.option`. When you have an expression, you need to supply the property name explicitly.

You *may* have wanted:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize({ // SQL constructor
  database: config.db.database,
  user: config.db.user,
  password: config.db.password,
  option: config.db.option
});
```

...but you'll need to double-check the property names (on the left before the `:`).